# how do you LIMIT a random number of IDs from a sqlite query?

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am working with a SQLite database in my application.  The app is supposed to select a specified set of question IDs, in a random order.  I also want to limit the questions to JUST the 21 IDs I specified.  However, whenever I run the application, I am able to answer a 22nd question.  I have 2 issues.

1. I dont think my sql query is selecting the right question IDs as specified in the statement.
2. After the 21st question is answered, the application should stop and not allow any further test material to be viewed.  This is not happening either.

I am relatively new to android library projects and SQLite, and help would be appreciated!

See my GTestBankDB class file below:

```
public class TestBankDB {
private static final String DEFAULT_DB_NAME = "test.db";
private static final String TEMP_DB_NAME = "temp.db";

private SQLiteDatabase db;
private static SQLiteDatabase testDatabase;

public enum TestType {
    SEEN_LEAST,
    MISSED_MOST
}

public TestBankDB(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    this.db = db;
}

public void close() {
    db.close();
    db = null;
}


public int getDataVersion() {
    return getInt("select max(id) from version");
}

public String getEquationName(int id) {
    return getString("select file_name from equations where id = " +     id).toLowerCase();
}

public void setGlobalStats(int questionId, int seenCount, int correctCount) {
    String sql = String.format("update questions set global_count = %d,                              global_correct = %d where id = %d", seenCount, correctCount, questionId); 
    db.execSQL(sql);
}

public List<Integer> getQuestionsForSubjects(int[] subjectIds, TestType type, boolean favoritesOnly) {

    // Gather individual questions
    String sql = "select id from questions where subject in (" + join(subjectIds) + ") and (case_id is null or case_id == 0) " + (favoritesOnly ? "and favorite > 0" : "");

    //String sql = "SELECT id from questions WHERE ID IN (84, 8791, 8349)";

    // pulls only questions with tables in them, note encryption in LIKE condition
    // String sql = "select id from questions where qtext LIKE '%<Q98Y5%' and subject in (" + join(subjectIds) + ") and (case_id is null or case_id == 0) " + (favoritesOnly ? "and favorite > 0" : "");

    switch (type) {
        case SEEN_LEAST: sql += " ORDER BY SEEN_COUNT, RANDOM()"; break;
        case MISSED_MOST: sql += " ORDER BY INCORRECT_COUNT DESC, SEEN_COUNT, RANDOM()"; break;
    }
    //Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, new String[]{});
    Cursor cursor = query(sql);

    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        list.add(cursor.getInt(0));
    }
    LogIt.d(this, "Loaded question count = " + list.size());
    cursor.close();

    // Gather case questions
    sql = "select id, case_id from questions where subject in (" + join(subjectIds) + ") and case_id > 0 " + (favoritesOnly ? "and favorite > 0" : "") + " order by case_id, id";
    List<Integer> questionIdList = null;
    List<CaseGroup> caseList = new ArrayList<CaseGroup>();
    //cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, new String[]{});
    cursor = query(sql);
    int currentCase = -1;
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

        int questionId = cursor.getInt(0);
        int caseId = cursor.getInt(1);

        if (currentCase < 0 || currentCase != caseId) {
             questionIdList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
             caseList.add(new CaseGroup((int)(MiscUtil.random()*list.size()), questionIdList));
```

//              caseList.add(new CaseGroup(caseList.size(), questionIdList)); // Put case questions at front
                 currentCase = caseId;
            }

```
        questionIdList.add(questionId);
    }
    cursor.close();

    Collections.sort(caseList);
    while (caseList.size() > 0) {
        CaseGroup group = caseList.remove(0);
        list.addAll(group.idx, group.questionIds);
        for (int i = 0; i < caseList.size(); i++) {
            caseList.get(i).idx += group.questionIds.size();
        }
    }

    return list;
}

public String getCaseText(int id) {
    return Allen.decrypt(getString("select text from cases where id = " + id));
}

public Subject getSubject(int id) {
    String name = getString("select subject from subjects where id = " + id);

    String sql = id == 0 ? 
            "SELECT count(*), sum(SEEN_COUNT), sum(INCORRECT_COUNT), sum(FAVORITE) FROM questions" :
            "SELECT count(*), sum(SEEN_COUNT), sum(INCORRECT_COUNT), sum(FAVORITE) FROM questions WHERE SUBJECT = " + id;

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, new String[]{});
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    int questionCount = cursor.getInt(0);
    int seenCount = cursor.getInt(1);
    int incorrectCount = cursor.getInt(2);
    int favoriteCount = cursor.getInt(3);
    cursor.close();

    Subject subject = new Subject(id, name, questionCount, seenCount, incorrectCount, favoriteCount); 

    return subject;
}

public List<Integer> getAllSubjects() {

    String sql = "select id from subjects";
    //Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, new String[enter code here]{});
    Cursor cursor = query(sql);

    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        list.add(cursor.getInt(0));
    }

    cursor.close();

    return list;
}

private String join(int[] items) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        builder.append(items[i]);
        if (i < items.length-1) {
            builder.append(",");
        }
    }

    return builder.toString();
}

public void resetPerformanceStatistics() {
    db.execSQL("update questions set seen_count = 0, incorrect_count = 0");
}

public void resetFavoriteQuestions() {
    db.execSQL("update questions set favorite = false");
}

public void resetNeverShowQuestions() {
    db.execSQL("update questions set never_see = false");
}

public void failQuestion(int id) {
    db.execSQL(String.format("update questions set incorrect_count = (SELECT incorrect_count FROM questions where id = %d)+1 where id = %d", id, id));
}

public void favoriteQuestion(int id, boolean favorite) {
    db.execSQL(String.format("update questions set favorite = %d where id = %d", favorite ? 1 : 0, id));
}

public void neverShowQuestion(int id, boolean neverShow) {
    db.execSQL(String.format("update questions set never_see = %d where id = %d", neverShow ? 1 : 0, id));
}

public Question getQuestion(int id) {
    // Get question
    //String sql = "select id, subject, qtext, answer_1, answer_2, answer_3, answer_4, answer_5, answer_6, answer_7, answer_8, rationale, favorite, case_id, global_count, global_correct from questions where id = " + id;
    //sql = "select id, subject, qtext, answer_1, answer_2, answer_3, answer_4, answer_5, answer_6, answer_7, answer_8, rationale, favorite, case_id, global_count, global_correct from questions where id = 2180";

    // Some test questions with htmlSymbols in them
    String sql = "SELECT id, subject, qtext, answer_1, answer_2, answer_3, answer_4, answer_5, answer_6, answer_7, answer_8, rationale, favorite, case_id, global_count, global_correct FROM questions WHERE ID IN (58, 127, 216, 291, 809, 1638, 1954, 1966, 2115, 2442, 3253, 3538, 3650, 4033, 4062, 5150, 7946, 7967, 2663, 3704, 5248) ORDER BY RANDOM()";

    //LogIt.d(TestBankDB.class, "getQuestion() id = " + id);
    //LogIt.d(TestBankDB.class, "sql = " + id);

    Cursor cursor = query(sql);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    Question q = Question.from(cursor);
    cursor.close();
    return q;
}

public void questionAnswered(int id) {
    db.execSQL(String.format("update questions set seen_count = (SELECT seen_count FROM questions where id = %d)+1 where id = %d", id, id));
}

public int getInt(String sql) {

    //Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, new String[]{});
    Cursor cursor = query(sql);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int value = cursor.getInt(0);
    cursor.close();

    return value; 
}
public String getString(String sql) {

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, new String[]{});
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String value = cursor.getString(0);
    cursor.close();

    return value; 
}

private class CaseGroup implements Comparable<CaseGroup> {
    int idx;
    List<Integer> questionIds;
    public CaseGroup(int idx, List<Integer> questionIds) {
        this.idx = idx;
        this.questionIds = questionIds;
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(CaseGroup o) {
        return idx < o.idx ? -1 : idx == o.idx ? 0 : 1;
    }
}

public Cursor managedQuery(Activity activity, String sql) {
    Cursor c = query(sql);
    activity.startManagingCursor(c);
    return c;
}

public Cursor query(String sql) {
    return db.rawQuery(sql, null);
}

public boolean isClosed() {
    return !db.isOpen();
}

public static TestBankDB getDefault(Context context) {
    //return new TestBankDB(context.openOrCreateDatabase(DEFAULT_DB_NAME, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null));
    if (testDatabase == null || !testDatabase.isOpen()) {
        LogIt.d(TestBankDB.class, "CREATING DEFAULT DATABASE");
        testDatabase = context.openOrCreateDatabase(DEFAULT_DB_NAME, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);
    }
    return new TestBankDB(testDatabase);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure the issue is on your SQL query, but I'm more interested in how you handle showing the next question. Assuming that you always call `getQuestion()` to get next question, then there should be a checking if it's already called 21 times. I'm also afraid that you can have duplicate questions with current approach.

Comment: do you know how i would set up the check to see if it has been called 21 times?  I am researching how to limit the rows AND keep the query from returning the same ID twice, haven't found much...any idea there would be cool! I am new on this project, and the code was made by the previous developer.  I am not sure at the moment how he is handling the question calling. I am investigating tonight

Comment: I have the idea, but the change might be big since it depends on question calling code. Later, after you amend the code on your question, I'll check it back.

Comment: the code already built for the database normally runs without duplicating questions as they are answered.  I'm spinning tires trying to find out why when I limit the question set to 21 randomly selected questions, it seems to ignore the limit and then start throwing in duplicates.  I have not changed the SQL for the getQuestion query other than inputting the specific IDs and adding the RANDOM() order by clause.  here is the code for the full Database activity which handles the delivery of question material to the application UI.  see my question edit